# Customized Component for C# SerialPort

Tags: c#, thread-safety, serial-port

I am writing a component it has a serial port (C# Component) and some other functions and events, when data is received it is processed,then the corresponding event is executed.

My problem was: 
When event executed, the following error occurred in runtime.

*Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'XXXXX' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.*

I searched and found these solutions.

1. Use Delegate and Invoke.
2. Use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem.

But these solutions do not run my event Immediately.

Now I want my event be immediately executed  without error.

Thanks.

**Additional descriptions:**

The timer component's ***tick*** event occur after elapsed time and inside it you can work with UI.
So I want my events be like tick and I have my own customized parameter **CustomEventArgs** and intend to use it instead **EventArgs** parameter,what should I do?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/CSharpAsynchronousHelper2.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thanks for your answers.

I found one solution for "cross-thread..." error, just set ***CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;***.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false; //just add this
}
```

Although I found why has delay.

.Net's **SerialPort** has property with **ReceivedBytesThreShold** name and 1 default value. And usually my received packet size is more than 50.

**Overhead** was causes to delay.

[MSDN Help For ReceivedBytesThreShold](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.receivedbytesthreshold.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can run the event, you just can't update the UI.  So, fire the event as you like, do whatever processing needs to be done without touching the UI, then perform an [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) to update the control (UI).

Comment: I want to show processed data immediately in UI,I have a camera connected to my PC serial port which continuously sends commands with the baud rate of 57600.  one out of all six commands is GPS position command. I need to show the data of this command to user. How can I see the data?

Comment: You can store the data from the serial port so the UI can later access it.  If you need to see all values, queue the data.  If you only need the most current value, store the latest value and let the UI access it (taking care to use 'lock' around the access in both threads).  This should happen fast enough to appear 'real time'.

You could also read the serial port synchronously on the UI thread, but the UI response may get choppy.  You can't just place it in a loop, since the UI thread needs to handle the paint messages.  You would need to use the Windows.Forms timer to do the polling.

Answer (score 1):

> I searched and found these solutions.
>
> 1. Use Delegate and Invoke.
> 2. Use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem.

Option 2) is not applicable here. Option 1) is your solution, you will find it is fast enough. It is faster than the user, and that all that matters.

Just design you system so that there is a sharp divide between GUI and non-GUI code. You should probably make the GUI delay even bigger by using BeginInvoke() in order not to block your data-processing.